# how to remove special character from string?

Tags: c#, regex, string, special-characters

my current scenario is , I have a string like "XYZName" but it should take only first 3 character and in those 3 character there shouldn't be any special character.

Example : "XYZName"
result should be: XYZ

and another requremnt is
Example : "X.YZName" or "XY-ZName"
result should be: XYZ

first example is done but not able to implement second example.
my code is

```
 comName = (comName .Replace(".", string.Empty).Length >= 3
                    ? comName .Replace(" ", string.Empty).Substring(0, 3)
                    : comName .Replace(" ", string.Empty)).ToUpper();
```

how to do this ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you consider to be a special character? Or better yet, what is your set of "safe" characters?

Comment: I want first 3 character without " .", "-" , "@"  and so on

Comment: So only the letters A-Z are acceptable? No numbers?

Comment: number is also fine

Comment: So only A-Z and numbers? You have to be precise about this or else we might give you a solution that includes characters you don't want, or excludes characters that you do want.

Answer (score 0):

**Update after comment that digits are also allowed**

```
comName = Regex.Replace(comName, @"[^a-zA-Z\d]", "").Substring(0, 3);
```

The regular expression uses a negated set, so any character other than `a-z`, `A-Z` or a digit (`\d`) will be removed.

After the characters are removed, `Substring` takes the first 3.

---

If you're using C#8+ you could replace the `Substring` with a Range:

```
comName = Regex.Replace(comName, @"[^a-zA-Z\d]", "")[..3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure to first match 3 times a char A-Z with optional chars other than A-Z or a whitespace char in between:

```
^[A-Z][^\sA-Z]*[A-Z][^\sA-Z]*[A-Z]
```

See a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5bA-Z%5d%5b%5e%5csA-Z%5d*%5bA-Z%5d%5b%5e%5csA-Z%5d*%5bA-Z%5d&i=XYZName%0d%0aX.YZName%0d%0aXY-ZName&o=m) for the matches.

Then from those matches, remove all chars other than A-Z:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[A-Z][^\sA-Z]*[A-Z][^\sA-Z]*[A-Z]");
string[] strings = {"XYZName", "X.YZName", "XY-ZName"};

foreach (String s in strings)
{
    var m = regex.Match(s);
    if (m.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"[^A-Z]+", ""));
    }
}
```

Output

```
XYZ
XYZ
XYZ
```

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/WVM5Al).

---

Or you can use 3 capture groups and directly print the value of the groups.

```
^([A-Z])[^\sA-Z]*([A-Z])[^\sA-Z]*([A-Z])
```

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/jXoq9Y) | [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iXcBwZ/1)